# I can't connect my bot to Cortana in the Azure portal

Tags: azure, botframework, cortana, azureportal

I have created a bot using the Microsoft Bot Framework, which is working fine and I'm trying to connect it to the channel Cortana and it gives me the error "There was an error saving the channel"

Here is the error screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Do you see any errors in the browser console?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the cortana channel settings?

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: I have some questions as well. Are you using Bot Framework V3 or V4? And what language are you using (e.g. C# or Node)? When you say it's working fine, do you mean you've tested it in other channels? Which channels?